# Hystrix: How to capsule multi calls

Tags: java, jboss, hystrix, netflix

I am using Hystrix to improve my services. How can I decapsulate the service calls into Hystrix. I know you can create for each call a special hystrix-class, but this would be too much work without using Spring!

I try to describe my problem with pseudocode:

```
public class HystrixController extends HystrixCommand {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HystrixController hystrixController = new HystrixController();
        System.out.print(hystrixController.execute());

    }

    private final ExampleService exampleService;

    protected HystrixController() throws Exception {
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("ExampleGroup"));
        this.exampleService = new ExampleService();
    }

    // Call 1
    public List getItemsAsList() {
        return exampleService.getItemsByContractId(contractID);
    }

    // Call 2
    public List getItemsByName() {
        return exampleService.getItemsByName(contractID);
    }

    // How can I isolate the two calls ? The run() only allows me to use one.
    @Override
    protected List run() throws Exception {
        return getItemsAsList();
    }

}
```

In the example you can see it is only possible to execute only one call. I would like to have something like that:

```
public class HystrixController extends HystrixCommand {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HystrixController hystrixController = new HystrixController();
        System.out.print(hystrixController.execute(1));
        System.out.print(hystrixController.execute(2));

    }

    private final ExampleService exampleService;

    protected HystrixController() throws Exception {
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("ExampleGroup"));
        this.exampleService = new ExampleService();
    }

    // Call 1
    public List getItemsAsList() {
        return exampleService.getItemsByContractId(contractID);
    }

    // Call 2
    public List getItemsByName() {
        return exampleService.getItemsByName(contractID);
    }

    // Multi Threads
    @Override
    protected List run_getItemsAsList() throws Exception {
        return getItemsAsList();
    }
    @Override
    protected List run_getItemsByName() throws Exception {
        return getItemsByName();
    }

}
```

Thanks you in advance and I am sorry for my broken English

Comment: I solve it on my own by using Aspect or JAVANICA.